# Attaching two NSString Objects w/ a space in the middle?

Tags: iphone

For example,

NSString *firstname = @"Test";
NSString *lastname = @"User";

NSString *fullname = ???????? (so it reads "Test User" <- space added in middle)

or would it have to be

NSMutableString *fullname = ???? with some operation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstname, lastname];
```